# In R, how do I create a long frequency table for every unique combination of the other columns

Tags: r, melt

Here are the first few rows of my table...

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wbxvJ.png)

In R, how do I create a long table where Col A and Col B show every possible combination and Col C contains either a or b (or c or d or whatever its value might be), and Col D shows the frequency of Col C value for each combination of Col A and B.

Using the example above, the results should look like this (showing just the first few rows)...

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nEivF.png)

I tried combinations of melt() and table() with little success.

Comment: Please do not post (only) an image of code/data/errors: it breaks screen-readers and it cannot be copied or searched (ref: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557 and https://xkcd.com/2116/). Please include the code, console output, or data (e.g., `data.frame(...)` or the output from `dput(head(x))`) directly into a [code block]. (Please rollback your edit so that others can use your data.)

Answer (score 0):

```r
as.data.frame.table(xtabs(~ ColA + ColB + ColC, dat))
#   ColA ColB ColC Freq
# 1    1    1    a    2
# 2    2    1    a    0
# 3    1    2    a    1
# 4    2    2    a    0
# 5    1    1    b    1
# 6    2    1    b    2
# 7    1    2    b    1
# 8    2    2    b    1
```

---

Data

```r
dat <- structure(list(ColA = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L), ColB = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L), ColC = c("a", "a", "b", "b", "a", "b", "b", "b")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -8L))
```